# Twilio app works while hosted on Google App Engine but not locally in the PHP SDK

Tags: php, google-app-engine, twilio

When trying to create a new sub account, this code works when deployed (on both https:// and http:// appspot URLs) but not locally in the SDK:

```
require 'php/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php';
require 'php/includes/twil_creds.php';

$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 

try {
    $account = $client->accounts->create(array(
        'FriendlyName' => 'New Account'
    )); 
} catch(Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

When I run it locally I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in C:\ivr3mil\php\twilio-php\Services\Twilio\HttpStream.php on line 62

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\ivr3mil\php\twilio-php\Services\Twilio\HttpStream.php on line 62

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts.json): failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\ivr3mil\php\twilio-php\Services\Twilio\HttpStream.php on line 62

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_HttpStreamException' with message 'Unable to connect to service' in C:\ivr3mil\php\twilio-php\Services\Twilio\HttpStream.php:65 Stack trace: #0 C:\ivr3mil\php\twilio-php\Services\Twilio.php(226): Services_Twilio_HttpStream->__call('post', Array) #1 C:\ivr3mil\php\twilio-php\Services\Twilio.php(226): Services_Twilio_HttpStream->post('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array, 'FriendlyName=Ne...') #2 C:\ivr3mil\php\twilio-php\Services\Twilio\ListResource.php(92): Services_Twilio->createData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array) #3 C:\ivr3mil\php\twilio-php\Services\Twilio\Rest\Accounts.php(23): Services_Twilio_ListResource->_create(Array) #4 C:\ivr3mil\twiltest.php(11): Services_Twilio_Rest_Accounts->create(Array) #5 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php(106): require('C:\\ivr3mil\\twil...') #6 {main} thrown in C:\ivr3mil\php\twilio-php\Services\Twilio\HttpStream.php on line 65
```

The SDK is up to date and I downloaded the PHP Library from Twilio directly yesterday.

Any input as to why this is happening would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a valid SSL certificate on & for your machine?  From the error messages it definitely looks like Twilio wants one!

Comment: I don't and I thought that would be the case, however, as noted, everything runs fine when accessed from a unencrypted url not providing an SSL certificate. Also none of the Google or Twilio documentation on using both services together make any reference to needing to set up SSL locally. Has no one else encountered this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I fixed the problem. Edit `Twilio.php`, right above `verify_peer`, add this line:

```
'cafile'        => '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt',
```

This fix worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 running PHP 5.5.9.

Answer (score 1):

I can't upvote or comment but Ron DeFulio's fix worked for me as well.

Hoping someone from Twilio sees this one and chimes in.

I've added a link to this thread to my open support ticket with Twilio regarding this same issue.